# Missing XSLT Options for input and output XML result

Tags: xml, xslt

I am evaluating if XSLT can achieve the following transformation:

Input XML:

```
<ROOT>
    <A>
        <B>
            <B1>Tech1</B1>
            <B2>Tech2</B2>
            <B3>Tech3</B3>
        </B>
        <C>Microsoft</C>
    </A>
    <A>
        <B>
            <B1>Tech11</B1>
            <B2>Tech12</B2>
            <B3>Tech13</B3>
        </B>
        <C>Microsoft</C>
    </A>
    <A>
        <B>
            <B1>Tech101</B1>
            <B2>Tech102</B2>
            <B3>Tech103</B3>
        </B>
        <C>Google</C>
    </A>
    <A>
        <B>
            <B1>Tech104</B1>
            <B2>Tech105</B2>
            <B3>Tech106</B3>
        </B>
        <C>Google</C>
    </A>
    <A>
        <B>
            <B1>Tech-1</B1>
            <B2>Tech-2</B2>
            <B3>Tech-3</B3>
        </B>
        <C>IBM</C>
    </A>
</ROOT>
```

Output Expected:

```
<ROOT>
    <Company>
        <C>Microsoft</C>
        <B>
            <B1>Tech1</B1>
            <B2>Tech2</B2>
            <B3>Tech3</B3>
        </B>
        <B>
            <B1>Tech11</B1>
            <B2>Tech12</B2>
            <B3>Tech13</B3>
        </B>
    </Company>
    <Company>
        <C>Google</C>
        <B>
            <B1>Tech101</B1>
            <B2>Tech102</B2>
            <B3>Tech103</B3>
        </B>
        <B>
            <B1>Tech104</B1>
            <B2>Tech105</B2>
            <B3>Tech106</B3>
        </B>
    </Company>
    <Company>
        <C>IBM</C>
        <B>
            <B1>Tech-1</B1>
            <B2>Tech-2</B2>
            <B3>Tech-3</B3>
        </B>
    </Company>
</ROOT>
```

I already tried to use the Key and generate-id() though I am stuck to get the output with all child node. As per my analysis I am getting the below output but that is not as per expectation, seems I am missing something here,

```
<ROOT>
    <Company>
        <C>Microsoft</C>
        <B>
            <B1>Tech1</B1>
            <B2>Tech2</B2>
            <B3>Tech3</B3>
        </B>
    </Company>
    <Company>
        <C>Google</C>
        <B>
            <B1>Tech101</B1>
            <B2>Tech102</B2>
            <B3>Tech103</B3>
        </B>
    </Company>
    <Company>
        <C>IBM</C>
        <B>
            <B1>Tech-1</B1>
            <B2>Tech-2</B2>
            <B3>Tech-3</B3>
        </B>
    </Company>
</ROOT>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:key name="Company" match="A" use="C/text()" />

<xsl:for-each select="A[generate-id()=generate-id(key('Company',C/text()))] ">
<ROOT>
  <Company>
    <C><xsl:value-of select="C/text()"/></C>
    <B>
      <B1></B1>
      <B2></B2>
      <B3></B3>
    </B>
  </Company>
</ROOT>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Please add your XSLT to the question.

Comment: added the XSLT, could you please review and let me know what is missing here?

Comment: Please be aware that XSLT grouping problems are much easier with XSLT 2.0+. If you're constrained to use the older XSLT 1.0 version, please say so by tagging the question xslt-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) (which you are attempting to implement here) has two parts.

First you create a group for each distinct value - this part can look like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="some-elem[generate-id() = generate-id(key('your-key', some-value)[1])]">
```

Then you do something for each member of the current group - typically by:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('your-key', some-value)">
```

Applied to your example, this would translate to:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="Company" match="A" use="C" />

<xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <ROOT>
        <xsl:for-each select="A[generate-id()=generate-id(key('Company',C))] ">
            <Company>
                <xsl:copy-of select="C"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('Company',C)/B"/>
            </Company>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ROOT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```